# How to do `FILTER (x IN ( ... ) )` in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to load all the subtaxons of Biota/Q2382433 (i.e. entities with P271 "parent taxon" pointing to Q2382433) in Wikidata.

The following query [works fine](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fclass%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fclasses%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20wdt%3AP171%20%3Fitem.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28wd%3AQ2382443%20AS%20%3Fitem%29%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?class; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?classes)
WHERE {
    ?class wdt:P171 ?item.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    BIND(wd:Q2382443 AS ?item)
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

With `FILTER` instead of `BIND`, it yields [zero results](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fclass%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fclasses%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20wdt%3AP171%20%3Fitem.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fitem%20in%20%28wd%3AQ2382443%29%29%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?class; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?classes)
WHERE {
    ?class wdt:P171 ?item.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    FILTER(?item in (wd:Q2382443))
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

How can I get the query to work using `FILTER`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason on Wikidata when `itemLabel` is added to the SELECT clause, the filter won't work. However, if you remove it, the query works fine.

You could also redeclare the triple pattern with a new variable name and filter on it:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?class; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?classes)
WHERE {
    ?class wdt:P171 ?item .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }

    ?class wdt:P171 ?parentTaxon .
    FILTER(?parentTaxon IN (wd:Q2382443))
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

[Results](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fclass%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fclasses%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20wdt%3AP171%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20wdt%3AP171%20%3FparentTaxon%20.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3FparentTaxon%20IN%20%28wd%3AQ2382443%29%29%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)

Edit: `VALUE` also works:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?class; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?classes)
WHERE {
    ?class wdt:P171 ?item .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    VALUES ?item { wd:Q2382443 }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

[Results](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fclass%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fclasses%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20wdt%3AP171%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20wd%3AQ2382443%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)